# Freedom of Movement and Power Word Stun

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions

Does Freedom of Movement allow you to move even if you have the stunned condition from a spell such as Power Word Stun?

[Freedom of Movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/spells#FreedomofMovement)

> ..spells and other magical effects can neither **reduce the target’s speed** nor cause the target to be paralyzed or restrained

[Stunned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Stunned)

> A stunned creature is incapacitated (see the condition), **can't
>   move**, and can speak only falteringly.

Specifically, my confusion is that the text says "reduce the target's speed".

I'm not sure if reducing speed is the applicable case since stunned just says "can't move".

Plenty of other effects say something specifically about reducing a target's speed, but not the stunned condition.

To be clear, I understand that FoM does not in any way prevent a creature from being stunned (only paralyzed or restrained), but I am looking for specific rules regarding the question of "can't move" either being or not being a reduction in speed.

**So, RAW, does Freedom of Movement allow you to move while stunned by a magical effect?**

*Please be sure to reference as much as you can to rules and sources in your answers.*

Comment: Your interpretation of FoM and PWS was consistent with some previous editions of the game, but not 5e

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Freedom of Movement* explicitly disallows the application of two conditions to the subject of the spell, namely they can't be *paralyzed* nor *restrained*.

*Stunned* is also a condition. It is not listed under FoM as disallowed. *Stunned* also does not reduce the target's speed. It states that the target *can't move*, whereas other conditions, as you noted yourself, explicitly state an altered speed value.

The *paralyzed* condition is almost the same as the *stunned* condition, the only differences being that 1. a paralyzed creature can't even speak falteringly, 2. attacks targeting a paralyzed creature and coming from an attacker within 5 feet of the paralyzed creature are critical hits. *Paralyzed* inflicts another condition, *incapacitated* on the target. So does *stunned*. *Stunned* does not inflict *paralyzed* on the target. FoM explicitly disallows *paralyzed*, but it does not mention *stunned*, ergo FoM does not protect against *stunned*, nor against spells that apply *stunned*, such as Power Word Stun. Considering there's no *Power Word Paralyze* and no *Power Word Restrain*, this seems to be a conscious design choice.

I'm not sure I like this, but **this is how I read RAW: FoM does not allow movement when its target is *stunned* regardless what applied said condition to its target** (and no matter that *stunned* is a weaker version of *paralyzed*.)

-

*RAI* I think the reasoning behind this is that *stunned* affects your mind, not your *speed*. Your *speed* is the distance the creature can cover. When *stunned*, its *speed* is the same, only the will to cover the distance unaffected *speed* would allow it to cover is impacted. (Also, the word "move" in the definition of *stunned* covers not just the movement of the legs or similar which allows the creature to go some distance. A *stunned* creature doesn't gesticulate, etc either. At least in my interpretation.)

(PHB 5e 1st printing, 2014, no errata, pages 244, 291-292)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I think it's there in my answer, in the third sentence of the 2nd paragraph: "_Stunned_ also does not reduce the target's speed." In RAW, the definition of _stunned_ not featuring the word _speed_ means it isn't affected (imo.) RAI I think the reasoning is that _stunned_ affects your mind, not your speed. Your speed is the distance the creature can cover. When stunned, it's speed is the same, only the _will_ to cover the distance speed would allow it to cover is impacted. (Also, move covers not just the movement of the legs. A stunned creature doesn't gesticulate, etc. IMO. :))

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried to do that -- hope it helps. (If not, I might try again tomorrow, with a bit more brains, as I'm quite tired atm. Sorry. :))

Answer (score 4):

Freedom of Movement doesn't prevent one from becoming *stunned*, by Power Word Stun, or any other effect that would cause this condition.

Freedom of Movement only specifies that...

> ...spells and other magical effects can neither reduce the target's speed nor cause the target to be paralyzed or restrained. *(PHB p. 244)*

Jeremy Crawford, on Twitter, has also stated that [the spell does not prevent you from losing the ability to move altogether](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/975835542934794240), it just presents magical effects from reducing your speed to 0 or becoming paralyzed or restrained.